# Converting NSString to NSarray using componentsSeperatedByString problem

Tags: objective-c, mobile

First off I would like to thank everyone for attempting to solve my problem. I am kind of a noobie so any help will be appreciated.

I have declared (`NSString *data`) that has retrieved content from a website. I have tested through various parts of my code that the data is in the string and that it is proper.

The data in the string is EXACTLY as follows:

> blah 2222, 3333, 1111 222 444 5555,<br/> blah 3333, 4444, 2222
>   333 555, <br/> blah 4444, 5555, 3333 444 666

this pattern continues for a while. I want to parse this data in a array so it is separated by ",". Therefore; I declared an array called (`NSArray *storage`) and I will then do:

```
storage = [dat componentsSeperatedByString:","];
```

I then have a label called (`UILabel *label`). It is connected through the interface builder, the property is set as well as synthesize.

I then go:

```
label.text = [storage objectAtIndex:0];
```

I run the Iphone simulator and when i press the button in my app which will activate the change, the iphone simulator exists to the home screen where all the apps are located.
Why is this happening? why isn't it displaying `blah 2222`?

Thanks!

Comment: Can you check the contents of the debug/console pane in XCode?  It should provide you with the stack frame for the crash.

Comment: Code you provided here is correct, your app is probably crashing in some other place. Try running static analyzer first (shift + cmd + B in Xcode 4).

Comment: @ficheck I run the static analyzer and everything comes back "okay"

Answer (score 1):

`componentsSeparatedByString:` returns an autoreleased array. Your `storage` array is probably already deallocated when you tap the button. Use a retained property for the array instead of assigning it directly to the instance variable.

Comment: believe you are correct. How would I use the retained property? Do you mean @property (nonatomic, retain) NSSarray *storage?

Thanks again

Comment: Yes, don't forget to `@synthesize` the property in the .m file, then simply use `self.storage = ...` instead of `storage = ...`.

Answer (score 0):

you can use this piece of code:

```
NSString *data = @"blah 2222, 3333, 1111 222 444 5555,<br/> blah 3333, 4444, 2222 333 555, <br/> blah 4444, 5555, 3333 444 666";  
NSArray *storage = [data componentSeparatedBy:@","];  
NSString *first= [data objectAtIndex:0];  
NSString *second = [data objectAtIndex:1];
///... and so on
//or 
label.text = [data objectAtIndex:2];
```